# Fourier Transform of this function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to find if the Fourier transform of the following function is positive of not.
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2-e^{-x^2}}
$$
How can I find the Fourier transform? I started with the classical definition but I could not solve the integral.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I would comment that the function $f$ is not integrable ($f \notin L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for any $1 \leq p \leq 2$), so the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$ is likely not defined.

Comment: @JavaMan: You are right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one hand,  JavaMan is right: since the function $f$ is not in $L^1+L^2$ on $\mathbb R$, the classical 
definitions of the transform do not apply. On the other, the Fourier transform is positive [in the sense of distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tempered_distributions); 
that is, it is a positive measure on $\mathbb R$. A nice measure, actually: smooth function plus a single 
point mass at $0$. Indeed, we have a series
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-2^{-1}e^{-x^2}}
=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}e^{-nx^2}\right)
\tag1$$
which converges in almost every sense imaginable. The terms with $n\ge 1$ are Gaussians which 
transform to other Gaussians (*positive* functions). The term with $n=0$ is $\frac12$ which is of course 
not integrable, but its distributional Fourier transform is a positive point mass at $0$.